# Sproutcore theming not working

Tags: sproutcore

I'm following http://guides.sproutcore.com/theming_app.html#styling-a-button to know about creating themes in SC. I did copy the red color images to the resources folder and copied the

```
$theme.button { /* their code */}
```

to resources/button.css, and reloaded my app, as they said theme should be working now. But it is not working as expected. In command prompt able to see some logging activities. Please point me how to apply a theme. I am not much sure of the ruby language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your 'tmp' directory and then restart sc-server

Comment: Thanks Joe its working. But what is the tmp folder all about? do you know any links that can give details of this?